# How is it that adjusting a .ui file using Qt Creator can cause changes to a .h file during compilation?

Tags: c++, qt

I noticed that if I make changes to my .ui file (like add a PushButton widget for example) and compile my project (with that .ui file a part of it), then the corresponding entry (for the PushButton widget for example) in the .h file is added automatically during compilation (the line `QPushButton *examplePushButton` gets added under `public:` of my .h file for the class whose .ui file I edited).

I'm just wondering how this happens. Firstly, how does Qt know which file to add the line to (assuming it's Qt somehow doing this)? And what happens during compilation specifically that causes this? It's very interesting. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The build system silently lauched by QtCreator (IDE) runs uic.exe tool that "compiles" the .ui file into a.h file (that any compiler can understand while they do not understand .ui format).

You would experience this with any build system in any IDE correctly configured to work with Qt. It also does the same for moc generation (for signals/slots management).

To know if uic has to be run, it simply checks timestamps. If the .h is older than the .ui, it means the .h needs to be generated again. It's the same mecanism used by your compiler to decide if a .cpp has to be compiled or not (if no .obj/.o file is present or if it's older than the .cpp file).

Comment: Not just qtcreator. *Any* build system set up to handle Qt .ui files will deal with this if you teach it how to (and most already know) by running `uic` as a dependency. Be it CMake, QMake, SCons, Make or *whatever*. Even Visual Studio knows (more or less) how to deal with this (through cmake) these days.

Comment: Thank you for the answers jpo38 and @JesperJuhl! Jesper, could you explain what you mean by running `uic` as a dependency? Do you mean you have to add `uic` as a dependency to your build system and after that the build system will starting using it? That probably doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @JamesRonald uic is an executable that takes a .ui file as input and generates a .h file. It is invoked by your build system if correctly configured to build a Qt project.

Comment: @JamesRonald Ok, trying to explain what I mean: the header file depends on the ui file. The build system knows that to generate the header from the ui file it needs to run `uic`.

Answer (score 1):

"How is it that adjusting a .ui file using Qt Creator can cause changes to a .h file during compilation?"

In a nutshell; You change the ui file. The build system notices that the auto generated header (generated from the ui file) is now outdated. The build system runs `uic` to re-generate the header from the new ui file. Then continues compiling your code.